# Need to add/delete key-val, if key doesn't exists for nested dictionary of variables depth

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've two nested dictionaries of variable depth `orig_dict` , `new_dict`

```
orig_dict = {"a":1, "b":[{"c":{"d":2}, "e":[{"q":12}, {"a":2}]}, {"h":[1,2,3,4]}], "e":{"we":12}}
new_dict = {"a":2, "b":[{"c":{"d":3}, "e":[{"q":120}, {"a":2}, {"x":10000}]}], "e":{"we":12}, "f":100}
```

Here `new_dict` is the updates needed to be done in `orig_dict`,

1. if key doesn't exists add that key-val to `orig_dict`
2. if key in `orig_dict` doesn't exists in `new_dict` then delete key-val from `orig_dict`
3. if key matches skip changes

I've code which will process only dictionaries as values but not list

```
import collections
def map_and_update(orig_dict, new_dict):
    for key, val in new_dict.items():
        if isinstance(val, collections.Mapping):
            tmp = updatee(orig_dict.get(key, { }), val)
            orig_dict[key] = tmp
        else:
            orig_dict[key] = new_dict[key]
    return orig_dict
```

this will result:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': [{'c': {'d': 3}, 'e': [{'q': 120}, {'a': 2}, {'x': 10000}]}], 'e': {'we': 12}, 'f': 100}
```

but i expect

```
{'a': 1, 'b': [{'c': {'d': 2}, 'e': [{'q': 12}, {'a': 2}, {'x': 10000}]}], 'e': {'we': 12}, 'f': 100}
```

> Note: Above i'm just copying the value of `new_dict` to `orig_dict` if i
>   see a list, but it should parse through list even and check whether
>   dict exists or not if exists then again do map

Comment: I don't see where you check if key exists. I see only that you always copy value from one dict to another.

Comment: what`s the implement of updatee?

Comment: Hi @furas, that is my question i want to implement for those given points and yes till copying value i've done

Comment: `if key not in orig_dict: orig_dict[key] = new_dict[key]`

Comment: furas here main point is to parse through nested dictionary with variable depth and contains list of dicts as a value; here it'll parse through dict of dicts as a value but i need to implement for list of dicts as a value

Comment: Hi @suiwenfeng, are u asking about the function i've tried?

Comment: I was looking into a solution for this, but it seems like there are a lot of nuances. For example, what if the value for a given key differs between new_dict and orig_dict? What if a value for a given key is a list, but the sizes of the lists differ between new_dict and orig_dict? These are just some examples of odd cases that can be handled in numerous ways, I am not sure which would meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This code of mine is maybe not very readable, but at least it did finish the job. I dont have time right now, but if anyone want me to explain, i will edit this post later.

```
orig_dict = {"a":1, "b":[{"c":{"d":2}, "e":[{"q":12}, {"a":2}]}, {"h":[1,2,3,4]}], "e":{"we":12}}
new_dict = {"a":2, "b":[{"c":{"d":3}, "e":[{"q":120}, {"a":2}, {"x":10000}]}], "e":{"we":12}, "f":100}


for key, value in new_dict.items():
    if isinstance(value, list):
        for key1, value1 in new_dict['b'][0].items():
            if orig_dict['b'][0].get(key1):
                pass
            if len(new_dict['b']) != len(orig_dict['b']):
                del orig_dict['b'][len(new_dict['b']):]
            length = len(new_dict['b'][0]['e'])
            for i in range(length):
                for k, v in new_dict['b'][0]['e'][i].items():
                    try:
                        if orig_dict['b'][0]['e'][i].get(k):
                            pass
                        else:
                            orig_dict['b'][0]['e'][i][k]=v
                    except:
                        orig_dict['b'][0]['e'].append({k:v})
    elif orig_dict.get(key):
        pass
    else:
        orig_dict[key]=value


print(orig_dict)
```

Comment: Hi @Sinner Beekeeping, i have understood that you have hard-coded the values please make sure it shouldn't because I have huge dictionaries and gave you simple and understandable inputs but like key "b" i've many keys so i want it to be generic

Comment: Ok. I didn't know. I will try :)